# Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 with managed identity forbidden

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-managed-identity

I am trying to run a powershell command in my azure runbook. But I am getting a forbidden exception...
Probably due to insufficient permissions. But where can I find the permissions I need?

```
$AzureContext = (Connect-AzAccount -Identity -AccountId "<accountidguid>").context
    

Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName  -Name "myalertname" | Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -DisableRule:$true -TargetResourceRegion " "
```

> Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Null/Empty, Code:
> Null, Status code:Forbidden, Reason phrase: Forbidden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested it in my environment by ***providing the managed identity `Reader` role in my subscription*** . I was ***able to get the alert rule*** but ***not able to perform the `Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2`*** which errored out like below:

[image]

***To solve the above you can either provide [***`Contributor`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#contributor) or [***`Monitoring Contributor`***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#monitoring-contributor) role to the managed identity.***

```
Connect-AzAccount -Identity -SubscriptionId 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
Get-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ResourceGroupName 'ansumantest' -Name "testalretrule" | Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -DisableRule:$true -TargetResourceRegion " "
```

[image]

Comment: I had my Monitoring Contributor on the wrong resource. Changing it, fixed it.